# Including/Extending the Kernel doesn't add those methods on main:Object

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to add a method into the `Kernel` module, but instead of reopening the `Kernel` and directly defining an instance method, I'm writing a module and I want `Kernel` to `extend/include` that module.

```
module Talk
  def hello
    puts "hello there"
  end
end

module Kernel
  extend Talk
end
```

When I run this in IRB:

```
$ hello
NameError: undefined local variable or method `hello' for main:Object
from (irb):12
from /Users/JackC/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin/irb:16:in `<main>
```

If I check the `instance_methods` on `Kernel`, I can see #hello was added to the `Kernel`, but not in `main Object`.

I've also tried using `include`, but the same thing happens:

```
module Kernel
  include Talk
end
```

However, if I define it directly:

```
module Kernel
  def hello
    puts "hello there"
  end
end
```

Then it does get included in the `main Object`.

```
$ hello
hello there
 => nil
```

Including the `Talk` module in `Object` works too:

```
class Object
  include Talk
end
```

Perhaps I'm doing this wrong, or I'm missing something simple, but this behavior is confusing me.

Comment: Jack, @AlexKliuchnikau nailed it; please accept his answer! And check out the "Ruby Hacking Guide" which he posted a link to!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I will try to explain it a little bit deeper:

when you `include` module into some class, Ruby creates special internal *include class* and adds it to the hierarchy (please note that basically you are not allowed to see *include class* from Ruby programm, it is hidden class):

```
Given A inherits B
And we have a module C
When A includes C 
Then A inherits includeC inherits B
```

If included module has other included Modules, then includeModules will be created for these modules as well:

```
Given A inherits B
And we have a module C
And C includes module D
When A includes C
Then A inherits includeC inherits includeD inherits B
```

*Include class* C method table is a *link* to method table of original class C.

When you `extend` some object with a module, then this module is included into *singleton class* of this object, thus:

```
class << self; include C; end
# is the same as
extend C
```

Going to your example:

```
module Kernel
  extend Talk 
end
```

Here you include `Talk` module into singleton class of `Kernel` (`Kernel` is an object of class `Module`). This is why you can call `hello` method only on Kernel object: `Kernel.hello`.

If we write this:

```
module Kernel
  include Talk 
end
```

Then `Kernel` will internally inherit *include class* includeTalk (class with link to `Talk` methods).

But Kernel module is already included into `Object` - `Object` inherits its own includeKernel class and includeKernel class has link to method table of `Kernel` and does not see methods of new include classes of `Kernel`.

But now if you will re-include Kernel into Object, all Objects will see methods of Talk:

```
> module Talk
>   def hi
>     puts 'hi'
>   end
> end
 => nil 
> module Kernel
>   include Talk
> end
 => Kernel 
> hi
NameError: undefined local variable or method `hi` for main:Object
        from (irb):9
        from /usr/share/ruby-rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin/irb:16:in `<main>`
> class Object
>   include Kernel
> end
 => Object 
> hi
hi
 => nil
```

The solution for you probjem might be to extend *main object* with your new module:

```
extend Talk
```

Hope this is clarified a bit behaviour you observe :)

**UPDATE**

Will try to clarify your questions:

> I'm still a bit confused why I have to re-include Kernel in Object. In
>   cases that don't involve the main Object, I can instantiate an object
>   based on a class and then later reopen that class and include a
>   module, and that object will see methods in my module. Is there
>   something different about how main Object includes the Kernel? I'm
>   also not sure what you mean by "Object inherits its own includeKernel
>   class and includeKernel class..." Why doesn't it see the new included
>   module in Kernel?

You tell about the case with direct inclusion of module into class of an object:

```
module M
  def hi
    puts 'hi'
  end
end

class C
end

c = C.new
c.hi # => UndefinedMethod

class C
  include M
end

c.hi # => hi
```

in this case you will have object `c` of class `C`. Class `C` inherits `Object` (because it is an *instance* of `Class` class. c looks for its instance methods in his singleton class -> then in his class C -> then in parents of class C (in this case `Object` instance methods). When we include module `M` into class `C`, then `includeM` will be a superclass of `C` and if `c` will not find his instance method in his singleton class and `C` class, it will search for instance methods in `includeM`. `includeM` has a link to method table of `M` class (instance of `Module` class). Thus when `c` search for instance method `hi` it finds it in the `M` module.

But this is different from case when you include module `M` into `Kernel` module.
At the program start `Object` class includes module `Kernel`: `class Object; include Kernel; end`. This is why I say that `Object` inherits from `includeKernel`. `includeKernel` has link to method table of `Kernel` and when you change *method table of Kernel*, `includeKernel` will also see these changes:

```
module Kernel
  def hi # add hi method to method table of Kernel
    puts 'hi'
  end
end

hi # => hi # any Object now see method hi
```

But when you include module M into Kernel, then method table of Kernel is not changed. Instead Kernel will now inherit `includeM` *include class*. `includeKernel` don't see methods of `includeM` because it does not know about inheritance chain of `Kernel` and `includeM`, it only knows the method table of `Kernel`.

But when you re-include `Kernel` into `Object`, inclusion mechanism will see that `Kernel` includes `M` and will create includeM for `Object` as well. Now `Object` will inherit `includeKernel` will inherit `includeM` will inherit `BasicObject`.

Comment: Alex, thanks for your detailed explanation. I have a better understanding now, but I'm still a bit confused why I have to re-include `Kernel` in `Object`. In cases that don't involve the main `Object`, I can instantiate an object based on a class and then later reopen that class and include a module, and that object will see methods in my module. Is there something different about how main `Object` includes the `Kernel`?

I'm also not sure what you mean by "Object inherits its own includeKernel class and includeKernel class..." Why doesn't it see the new included module in `Kernel`?

Comment: @AlexKliuchnikau, thanks for this explanation. It is different from what is written in *"The Ruby Programming Language"* -- has this changed? But your answer works. @JackChu, if you try adding an instance method `hello` to `Kernel`, and then try `Object.new.hello`, it doesn't work. But if you re-include `Kernel` in `Object`, it works. So this is not just limited to the main object. It's all very confusing to me, because I have observed different behavior in the past.

Comment: @AlexD, this is not written in *The Ruby Programming Language* book because, I think, it is implementation details (you are not allowed to get an instance of include class in the Ruby code). They don't tell anything about *include classes* and IMHO this is an overlook. You get much deeper understanding of Ruby behavior and how `include` and `extend` methods work when you know how it is implemented internally. I took this information from the souce code of MRI. Also this information is available in [Ruby Hacking Guide](http://rhg.rubyforge.org/).

Comment: Thanks for the awesome resource! About *TRPL*, pg 251 states: "It is legal to include one module into another. Doing this simply makes the instance methods of the included modules into instance methods of the including module." And regarding method lookup, pg 258 states: "If no method `m` is found in the class, Ruby searches the instance methods of any modules included by the class of `o`". Taken together, those statements clearly indicate that if `class A` includes `module B`, and then `module B` includes `module C`, the methods of `C` should be available to instances of `A`.

Comment: @AlexD, *The Ruby Programming Language* is incorrect. MRI and RubySpec are "specification" :) Looks like I found a spec for this case in the *RubySpec*: https://github.com/rubyspec/rubyspec/blob/master/core/module/include_spec.rb#L31

Comment: @AlexKliuchnikau: Thanks for clearing that up. So `Object` includes the `Kernel` meta class, so if you `include` new modules into `Kernel`, `Object` does not pick it up. Re-including `Kernel` into `Object` adds the `Talk` meta class to the `Object` inheritance chain. I think I understand, thanks!

Comment: @AlexKliuchnikau, unfortunately your line-specific link to RubySpec experienced only a brief life of validity. It should be [here](https://github.com/rubyspec/rubyspec/blob/764b5c966bfa17aacc1887682b76194db371889f/core/module/include_spec.rb#L31) for that particular commit. Would that GitHub eased linking to source lines *in the current commit*! While (naturally) browsing on the master branch, GitHub currently & stupidly requires three(!) clicks to generate a line-specific link for future use: History, Browse code (at the top of the history list) and again clicking the desired line.

Comment: @AlexKliuchnikau I've requested (and [blogged](http://markdblackwell.blogspot.com/2014/01/github-should-ease-line-specific-links.html)) GitHub show a button for this in their GUI. They answered that hitting 'Y' (on GitHub) will convert a line-specific web URI to the same line in the latest commit. But...this is awkward, unobvious, and rather unknown! GitHub's UI flaw has generated many (other) obsolete links like the one you experienced. ;/

Answer (score 4):

This is more a workaround than a solution, suitable if you don't want to define the function on main:

```
module Talk

  def self.extended(mod)
    mod.module_eval do
      def hello
        puts "hello there"
      end
    end
  end

end

module Kernel
  extend Talk
end
```

Incidentally, I wonder why the behaviour is different in this case. Shouldn't `module_eval` have the same effect as `module Talk; end`?

Comment: It does have the same effect. What you're doing is defining the methods on the `Kernel` module itself, and having `Talk` contain no methods.

Whereas `include` and `extend` modify the inheritance chain to say "also look here for methods", you are adding a method to `Kernel` directly, the same as if you put the declarations in `Kernel` itself.

Answer (score 3):

You want `include`, not `extend`.

`include` adds the contents of the module as instance methods (like when you open a class or module normally); `extend` adds them as class methods (so in your example, you could call `Kernel.hello`, though this isn't what you want).

You might now be inclined to try this:

```
module Talk
  def hello
    puts "hello there"
  end
end

module Kernel
  include Talk
end
```

But this won't work either, because `main` has already been instantiated, and `include` simply alters the ancestry of `Kernel`.

You could force `main` to include your module at runtime, like this:

```
# (in global scope)
class << self
  include Talk
end
```

This way, you're altering the metaclass of `main`, not `Kernel` (which would imply including it on a ton of other object you may not want).

If you do, you can also just do an `include Talk` in global scope, but beware that this will pollute integers and other things with your methods.

Comment: I've also tried include, but I get the same error. It's a little confusing, because if you look at Kernel.singleton_methods, you see methods like lambda, proc, and sleep. When you look at Kernel.instance_methods, you get hash, clone, dup, is_a?, and kind_of? The instance methods look like methods I'd call on an object. The singleton methods look like methods I'd call without a receiver, or with self being the receiver.

It looks like I'd want to add my method to the singleton_methods, so I used extend.

Comment: Does the trick using `class << self` solve your issue? If you only want to attack it to the `main` object, this is likely what you want.

The singleton methods are methods defined on the Kernel metaclass (which you can use to act on the Kernel module itself), whereas the instance methods are available on objects whose classes inherit from (or include) Kernel. `main` is in this category. I'm sorry if I'm not explaining this well.

Comment: You're right, I do want `include` and not `extend`. So,  `include` adds the methods to an anonymous proxy class on the Kernel class object. `extend` adds those methods to the Kernel singleton class. Is that right? The trick does work, but I'm trying to add this to a gem in a core_ext/kernel file and the main object isn't the scope in that case.

Comment: "...this won't work either, because `main` has already been instantiated". The fact that `main` has been instantiated is not relevant, as you can confirm by adding `hello` to `Kernel` and then trying `Object.new.hello`. @AlexKliuchnikau seems to be on the right track.

Comment: Just to clarify, when I say "adding `hello` to `Kernel`", I mean adding it by including a module, not adding it directly.

Comment: @AlexD There isn't a contradiction. The point is that the module was included too late, so that it is not in the inheritance hierarchy of the main object when you want it to be. I will admit that the other explanation is both clearer and in more depth, so I'll defer to it.