# Ruby's Mix-in chaining not working properly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm using Ruby 1.9.3 on Windows. So I want to add methods to be availble in console via `Kernel` class. Start console.

```
module Foo
  def bar
    puts "Method is in scope!!!"
  end
end
```

After add this to `Kernel` (which is part of `Object` class)

```
irb(main):008:0> Kernel.send(:include, Foo)
=> Kernel
irb(main):009:0> bar
"NameError: undefined local variable or method `bar' for main:Object"
# did not work, we need to re-include Kernel in Object class
irb(main):010:0> Object.send(:include, Kernel)
=> Object
irb(main):011:0> bar
Method is in scope!!!
=> nil
irb(main):012:0>
```

This should have worked only with `Kernel.send(:include, Foo)` or am I wrong? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, in this case you should extend `Object` directly. But if you're so inclined, you can extend `Kernel`, just don't forget to re-include it to Object again.

```
module Foo
  def bar
    puts "Method is in scope!!!"
  end
end

Kernel.send :include, Foo
# bar at this point will generate error

Object.send :include, Kernel
bar
# >> Method is in scope!!!
```

Also, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9240443/125816) for a much more thorough explanation.

Comment: Link bellow gives explanation. For me it is one of those "it's not a bug it's a feature" points but at least we know now why.

Comment: +1, thanks for that link. I wonder why it was designed this way? I guess this is what forces people use `included` hooks in order to inject other modules.