# undef methods from Kernel class still able to call them from Kernel.singleton_class

Tags: ruby

```
module Kernel
  undef rand
  undef srand
end
```

why Kernel.rand still working? I know the method is called on Kernel.singleton_class but the singleton class includes Kernel module which has the methods undefined. Is this just a case of ruby black magic or i'm missing something from ruby object model? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though this is a very bad practice to monkey-patch an existing main module like this, esp `Kernel` which is ancestor of every *object* in Ruby. It may have very bad & severe repercussions in your or other project, it is included. Though for understanding what is going on above with your code, you can change:

```
module Kernel
  undef rand
  undef srand
end
```

to

```
module Kernel
  class << self
    undef rand
    undef srand
  end
end
# OR, much cleaner:
Kernel.instance_eval { undef :rand, :srand }
```

by `class << self` you are hijacking the singleton class/eigenclass of Kernel and undefining the singleton methods `rand` and `srand` there. 
These are the singleton methods of kernel rather than the instance methods.

Orginally:

```
 Kernel.singleton_methods.grep(/rand/)
=> [:srand, :rand]
```

After:

```
 Kernel.singleton_methods.grep(/rand/)
=> []
```

> I know the method is called on Kernel.singleton_class but the singleton
>   class includes Kernel module which has the methods undefined.

`include` in a class/module doesn't include the *singleton methods* in that class/module. `rand` and `srand` are effectively only defined in singleton_class of Kernel and can only be undefined from there.

**UPDATE**:
As noticed, `rand` and `srand` in top-level object(`main`) will still work, but `Kernel.rand` and `Kernel.srand` will give NoMethodError. Reason:

When a module is *included* in a class or other module, Ruby internally creates a special *include class* which holds the reference for the module defined at that time, and adds that class in ancestor chain of the class(though hidden).
Now, `Object` has already *included* `Kernel` earlier. The methods present in Kernel at that instance are stacked in hidden *include class* and is available for `Object`. That's why, `main` (instance of Object) still holds the reference of those methods.
This is the reason why `rand` works but `Kernel.rand` doesn't.

Comment: The only purpose of this code is learning. :)
rand and srand methods are actually singleton methods and not instance methods of Kernel module. Make sense now. But then another question comes up. Even I have undef the methods why I'm still able to call them from top level? Thank you for your answer!

Comment: Yes, that's why I took liberty to explain the working concept behind it. :-) 
It doesn't get called after defining from top level, for me. Please check once.

Comment: I did check it. Called "rand" and "srand" after i have undef them on the Kernel mod and they still work. How's that possible? Tested on ruby 2.1. Thanks!

Comment: I checked it on mine now. You are right, `rand` is still functional from top-level (main) object, but `Kernel.rand` doesn't work anymore. This is surprising. Looking into it...

Comment: @Viorel Figured out. Added reason for that. Also found a good thread - http://stackoverflow.com/a/9240443/1376448 which explains the reason of `include` modules further. :)

Comment: maybe it has to do with rand and srand are actually private methods of top level object?

Comment: as far as i understand this has to do with strange nature of the top level object and how the top level code is being executed. Don't think i'm able to replicate this behaviour on any other classes/modules. Thank you for your answers!